# Update one value in params

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I am getting this in my params:

```
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"wdOkjrI8no6xcooBaNithP1KtVNvwvwyJL1vcEuFTSo=", "complete"=>"not completed", "commit"=>"Save Data", "task_form"=>{"rent_balance"=>"$900.00", "misc_balance"=>"$0.00", "total_balance"=>"$900.00", "date_of_petition"=>"", "nop_court"=>"Select", "index_number"=>""}, "id"=>"1059"}
```

I have to update value of `nop_court` to `nil` if its value is `'Select'`.
For that had written the following:

```
if params[:task_form][:nop_court] == "Select"
  @task.update_data_item_values(@task_form_attributes)
  @task.update_data_item_values(params[:task_form][:nop_court] => " ")
else
  @task.update_data_item_values(@task_form_attributes)
end
```

In `params[:task_form][:nop_court]` I am getting the value select so the above code is not working. How can I get only the params nop_court

Code inside the method called update_data_item_values is as:

```
  def update_data_item_values(task_form_attributes)
    #list of data items for task
    @task_data_items = self.data_items
    if task_form_attributes
    #updating value for each data item
      task_form_attributes.keys.each do |task_data_item_name|
        task_data_item = @task_data_items.select { |task_data_item| task_data_item.data_item_name == task_data_item_name}.first
        value = task_form_attributes[task_data_item_name]
        if task_data_item.present?
          if task_data_item.data_item_data_type == "date"
            if value.present?
              formatted_value = task_data_item.blank? ? Date.strptime(value, '%m-%d-%Y').strftime("%Y-%m-%d") : value
              #formatted_value = value.to_datetime.strftime('%m-%d-%Y') unless value.blank?
              data_item_value = formatted_value
            end
          else
            data_item_value = value
          end

        end
        task_data_item.update_attributes(:data_item_value => data_item_value) if task_data_item.present?
      end
    end
  end
```

Comment: Sorry, could you clarify, what is going wrong and what do you expect to be happening with this code? What do you mean by "I am getting the value select so the above code is not working"?

Comment: Can you expand on "it's not working"? Do you get an error? Are you getting an unexpected value?

Can you also include the contents of `update_data_item_values`?

Comment: Your condition says `params[:task_form][:nop_court] == "Select"` so you can be sure it will be that way inside your `if`. Therefore the parameter to the second `update_data_item_values` will be "Select" => " " which will be turned into into a `Hash` with just one entry. Are you sure this is what you want?

Comment: what is `@task_form_attributes`?

Comment: Holy verbosity batman

Comment: I was wondering how it was created rather than what you do with it...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Before your if statement I assume you are assigning @task_form_attributes as:

```
@task_form_attributes = params[:task_form]
```

Try updating this variable before calling update_data_item_values:

```
if params[:task_form][:nop_court] == "Select"
  @task_form_attributes[:nop_court] = " "
end

@task.update_data_item_values(@task_form_attributes)
```